# White bread toasted seems hotter than brown bread?

Tags: thermodynamics

Ok this is a bit of a random question but I 99% of the time use white bread for toast and I always toast my bread the same amount and every time I take it out it's too hot to handle and the butter melts instantly on it.

But this morning I used brown bread for the first time in forever and I noticed that even after getting it to the same amount of "toastiness" it was a lot cooler and I could easily handle it.

Is it something that's in the bread white bread or the fact that it's more dense that causes it to be hotter?

Comment: I think the amount of fat in the bread is crucial for its heat capacity. Can you check the figures for your specific brown and white bread?

Comment: @Joce Not in this moment in time (at work).

Comment: I'd go with the 'denser' explanation - if you've ever made white vs wheat bread (by hand or in a bread machine) it is pretty obvious that the wheat loaf has a higher density.

Comment: @JonCuster Yeah, it was the first thing I thought of so it's probably the reason